# Do cold/hot drinks have any effect on woodwinds and brass performers?

Tags: instruments, physics, temperature, physiology

Hey, I saw [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/726/does-environmental-or-food-drink-temperature-have-an-effect-on-the-voice) and I immediately remembered one or two teachers that kept saying that drinking cold/hot drinks before and/or during playing any woodwind or brass instrument was a bad thing, and I always followed that advice, but never really questioned it.

So, I couldn't help to wonder, besides the unfortunate lack of hygiene, Is there any disadvantage to this?
Does this have any effect?

Comment: I bet military band members would have a wealth of practical experience in this regard.

Comment: I don't know about the drinks, but I DO know that eating salty foods can hurt or swell your lips, making it hard to play and have clean attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a slight change in exhausted air. When throat is cold, somewhat colder exhausted air becomes more dense and that may be a subject of a slight pitch change.

There is another question if this change can be audible. If it is, I think it would be temporary - cold / hot throat quickly changes its temperature to the body's natural temperature level.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether or not the temperature of the drink affects your ability to play a horn, but my band director says that if you drink anything containing sugar it will either:

- Cause the inside of a brass instrument to rust more quickly than normal.
- Cause the pads of a woodwind instrument to become sticky and therefore prevent it from  forming a proper seal.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is burning your tongue with hot drink, or making your mouth go numb with cold drink.

The cold/hot drink might also have an effect on your throat. Banana can for example make it kind of sticky (eating banana and singing is not a nice combination), it might be the same with hot chocolate (in that case more from the milk or cream)...

Mostly guessing. The banana effect I have felt.

As a side note: I like to brush my teeth before playing the trumpet sometimes, and some brands of toothpaste make it hard to play, my lips are paralyzed.

I suppose reed instruments are more sensitive than brass.

Answer (score 1):

The only I can think of is that when you eat or drink, you potentially have more saliva in your mouth, combined with sugar etc that can make the mouth piece more dirty/disgusting. Personally, I often drink coffee (no sugar) close up to before I play <sub><sup>(I play Tuba)</sup></sub>. Actually in our orchestra practice (not professional orchestra...), the mid break is officially called a coffee break!